# How to use the word "repeat" correctly?

Tags: word-usage

> *My friend*: I am sorry, I did a mistake.
>
> *Me*: This is a normal way to learn things. Just don't repeat (**on**?) it **again**.

My question is if I can use the word "**again**" after "**repeat**" or it isn't logical. In addition I'd like to know if the preposition "**on**" is needed here or it's needless.

Comment: Although I'm not providing this as an answer, because it's an edge case, the two can be used together meaningfully in a sentence like this: *I have already repeated the mistake once; I want to make sure I don't repeat it again.* Here, *again* is referring to the repetition itself, not to the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should either be "Just don't repeat it." or "Just don't do it again."
Using the word "again" after "repeat" does not make sense because using "repeat" already implies that it is for the next time.
"On" is not needed in this sentence.

Also, another correction to the first sentence:
My friend: I am sorry, I **made** a mistake.

You don't do mistakes, you make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The last part of the sentence is uneccessary - repeating means doing something again. So

> Me: This is a normal way to learn things. Just don't repeat it.